# Replacing content inside HTML <p> tag having specific language characters using php

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

```
<p class="myClass">你好</p><p class="myClass">你好</p></div> <div class="myDiv">Integer in ante sit amet tellus sodales sagittis non sit amet nisi. Integer sollicitudin, orci nec tincidunt laoreet, dui quam tempor risus, sed mollis nisl libero nec ligula</div><p class="myClass">你好</p>
```

I am trying to replace only `<p class="myClass">你好</p>` But whole string is being replaced.

**Pattern:**

```
$pattern = "/<p class=\"myClass\">(.)*<\/p>/";
preg_replace($pattern,"",$string);
```

When I Put **p** tag on new line it works good. But having **p** tag Without space replacing all the string.

Comment: Try `<p class=\"myClass\">(.*?)<\/p>`

Comment: Or `/<p class=\"myClass\">[^<]+<\/p>/`

Comment: What you want bro. I think @Mohammad Already gave the answer.

Comment: It's more appropriate to use DOM parsing for this kind of tasks.

Comment: HTML and regex are not good friends. Use a parser, it is simpler, faster and much more maintainable.
See: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: @Toto What is it for?

Comment: Have you read the doc? You will also find usefull informations here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3577641/372239

Answer (score 0):

The `(.*?)` select all character but you need to select `<p>` so use `[^<]+` instead that select every character except `<`.

```
$pattern = "/<p class=\"myClass\">[^<]+<\/p>/";
preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/TPZeh)

Comment: This won't work if any other HTML element (e.g. `<span>`) is in the paragraph (now, only OP knows if that may or may not happen). PS: I wasn't the one downvoting the answer tho :)

Comment: @Jeto It doesn't mention in question

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
$str = '<p class="myClass">你好</p><p class="myClass">你好</p></div> <div class="myDiv">Integer in ante sit amet tellus sodales sagittis non sit amet nisi. Integer sollicitudin, orci nec tincidunt laoreet, dui quam tempor risus, sed mollis nisl libero nec ligula</div><p class="myClass">你好</p>';
preg_replace('#<p(.*?)>(.*?)</p>#is', '', $str);
```

It will replace all the `<p>` tags from the string.
Check this Fiddle :- https://3v4l.org/Un9Jh

Comment: You can use StackOverflow's own snippet function (edit: I'm stupid)

Comment: But that will be only for JS, I think

Comment: Oh, sorry lol, for some reason I thought it was JS, forget about it. Still waking up :)